# Modify a method using Annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How can I change what a method is doing in Java ?

I mean, I am trying to use annotations to make the following code

```
@Anno1(Argument = "Option1")
public class TestClass
{       
    @Anno2
    public void test()
    {
    }

}
```

Into

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static StaticReference z;

    public void test()
    {
           z.invokeToAll();
    }

}
```

This is a very simplified example of what I am trying to do. `Anno1` will have many possible combinations, but this is not my problem so far. My problem is how to add code to method `test()`

I am looking for a more generic solution if possible. Eg. A way to add every kind of code in the method (not just a way to `.invokeToAll()`)

So far I am using `import javax.annotation.processing.*;` and I have the following code, but I don't know how to go on from there

```
private void processMethodAnnotations(RoundEnvironment env)
{
    for (Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Anno2.class))
    {
        //If it is a valid annotation over a method
        if (e.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) 
        {
            //What to do here :S
        }else
        {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING,"Not a method!", e);               
        }           
    }
}
```

I have found something about Java Reflection but I have not found any source to help me with what I am doing.

Obviously I `extends AbstractProcessor` in my code

I have found this tutorial (http://www.zdnetasia.com/writing-and-processing-custom-annotations-part-3-39362483.htm) But this concerns creating a new class, not just changing a method. and the `javax.lang.model.elements` do not provide any way of editing that element (which in my case represents a Method).

I hope my question is clear and inline with the rules. If not please comment and I will clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Annotation processing is the wrong way to go for you, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation):

> When Java source code is compiled,
> annotations can be processed by
> compiler plug-ins called annotation
> processors. Processors can produce
> informational messages or create
> additional Java source files or
> resources, which in turn may be
> compiled and processed, but annotation
> processors cannot modify the annotated
> code itself.

People suggested to you the right way - AOP. Specifically, you can use AspectJ. "Quick  result" way is (if you use Eclipse):

1. Install [AJDT](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/) (AspectJ Development Tools)
2. Create an AspectJ project and add there your classes and annotations
3. Create Aspect:

   public aspect Processor {

   ```
    private StaticReference z;

    pointcut generic()
            // intercept execution of method named test, annotated with @Anno1
            // from any class type, annotated with @Anno2
        : execution(@Anno2 * (@Anno1 *).test())
            // method takes no arguments
        && args ();

    // here you have written what you want the method to actually do
    void around () : generic()  {
        z.invokeToAll();
    }
   ```

   }

now you can execute a test and you will see that it works ;) AJDT compiles code for you automatically, so do not need any manual work to do, hope that's what you called "magic" ;)

**UPDATE:**

if your code in the `test()` method depends on the `Anno1` annotation value, then inside aspect you can get class annotation for which it is executed this way:

```
void around () : generic()  {
    
    Annotation[] classAnnotations = thisJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getAnnotations();
    
    String ArgumentValue = null;
    for ( Annotation annotation : classAnnotations ) {
        if ( annotation instanceof Anno1 ) {
            ArgumentValue = ((Anno1) annotation).Argument(); 
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if ( ArgumentValue != null && ArgumentValue.equals("Option1")) {
        z.invokeToAll();
    }
    
}
```

where [thisJoinPoint](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-thisJoinPoint.html) is a special reference variable.

**UPDATE2:**

if you want to add `System.out.println( this )` in your aspect, you need to write there `System.out.println( thisJoinPoint.getThis() )`, just tested and it works. `thisJoinPoint.getThis()` returns you "this" but not exactly; in fact this is Object variable and if you want to get any propery you need either to cast or to use reflection. And `thisJoinPoint.getThis()` does not provide access to private properties.

Well, now seems that your question is answered, but if I missed anything, or you get additional question/problems with this way - feel free to ask ;)

Comment: You solution seems to be what I want, unfortunately due to weird reasons I may not use it. I have found a solution elsewhere (`Javassist`). Anyway I already gave you +1 and now an Accepted Answer for the effort and good answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Muggen hm, you can tell me about "weird reasons", so I could see if they really matter; maybe there is another way to stick with AOP (it looks easier to support..)

Comment: those weird reasons are `Academic Restrictions` ;). Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Muggen, I understand, but anyway interesting what can restrict. Really, just wondering - you should use Java only (so AspectJ is treated as "different" language), or you just don't have to look for easy solutions? ;)

Answer (score 10):

It's perfectly possible to do what you ask, although there is a caveat: relying on private compiler APIs. Sounds scary, but it isn't really (compiler implementations tend to be stable).

There's a paper that explains the procedure: [The Hacker's Guide to Javac](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Erni08b.pdf).

Notably, this is used by [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to provide automatic getter/setter generation (amongst other things). The [following article](http://notatube.blogspot.be/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html) explains how it does it, basically re-iterating what is said the aforementioned paper.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might see if the following boilerplate code will be useful:

```
public void magic(Object bean, String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (Method method : bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Anno2.class)) {
            // Invoke the original method
            method.invoke(bean, args);
            // Invoke your 'z' method
            StaticReference.invokeAll();
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative your might employ aspect oriented programming, for instance you have the [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) project.

Comment: Hm smart, but What if instead of `z.invokeToAll();` I want for example to do something like `System.out.println(this);` I am looking for a more generic solution if possible.

Comment: Printing `this` means to invoke `TestClass.toString()`. You can still do that if you prefer. Moreover, with reflection, you can access all properties of your annotated classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at all if it is even possible to change the source or byte code via annotations. From what your describing it looks as if [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) could provide a solution to your problem.

Your annotations are pretty similiar to the *pointcut* concept (they mark a location where code needs to be inserted) and the inserted code is close the *advice* concept.

Another approach would be parsing the java source file into an abstract syntax tree, modify this AST and serialize to a java compiler input.

Comment: AOP is the way to go here (+1). Modifying the AST is possible (I have done it successfully), but it's a dirty hack that relies on undocumented internal APIs that are subject to change

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends a suitable interface, you could wrap it in a DynamicProxy, which delegates all calls to the original methods, except the call to test.